# Reversing order of struct bitfields

Tags: c, binary

Im trying to implement a psuedo-bit-array in C, where I define a structure with 8, 1 bit members, and then converting its memory address to an `unsigned char`. This approach does work, yet it flips the order of the bits in the binary number. Eg. `127` would become `254`. How can I undo this?

```
struct bit_array {
    unsigned b8:1, b7:1, b6:1, b5:1, b4:1, b3:1, b2:1, b1:1;
};


unsigned char join(struct bit_array num) {
    return *(unsigned char*)&num;
}

int main() {
    struct bit_array test_bits = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    printf("%u", join(test_bits));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: probably an endianness issue

Comment: @SuperStormer i thought endianness only affected byte order

Comment: That depends on how you think they *should* be ordered. Keep in mind the ordering of bitfields is implementation defined.

Comment: @QuestionLimitGoBrrrrr and so it is, the size of  your `struct` is 4 bytes (`unsigned int`) not 1 (`unsigned char`). In consequence there are 3 padding bytes around your value and is affected by endianness.

Comment: @DavidRanieri how can i remove those extra three bytes then?

Comment: Use  `memcpy`, but as pointed out by @EmanuelP the ordering is implementation defined, this doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard specifies neither the order of bit-fields within whatever unit of storage is used for them nor the order of bits in an unsigned integer except to say they are implementation-defined and to imply the bit-fields are either high-to-low or low-to-high (rather than mixed).

C 2018 6.7.2.1 says:

> The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined.

C 2018 6.2.6.2 says unsigned integers are represented with pure binary, and a footnote indicates this means the values attributed to successive bits are successive powers of two. So there must be some “succession” of the bits, an order in which their positions in the succession correspond to their values. However, it is not possible to correlate this order with any hardware property, as nothing in C makes bits individually addressable, so there is no mechanism in C to discern a bit at a lower address than another or to otherwise inspect the individual bits in any memory cell (whether in register or main memory or elsewhere).

The C standard does not provide any means for a program to request that an implementation order the bits in a particular way.

If you wish the bit-fields to be allocated in the reverse order, you can reverse their declarations. However, this will not maintain that order in C implementations that allocate bit-fields in the other order.

According to the [GCC 10.3 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), section 4.9, its order of bit-fields within a unit is “Determined by ABI,” meaning it follows the Application Binary Interface for the target platform. So I expect the order is not selectable by a command-line switch. I also do not see a predefined preprocessor macro to report it.

In any case, using named bit-fields is generally not a good way to implement an “array” of bits. You can simply use bit operators to access the bits in a unit and can write functions to set and get them if desired:

```
unsigned int GetBit(UnitType u, int n) { return (u >> n) & 1; }
void SetBit(UnitType *u, int n, UnitType b) { *u ^= (((*u >> n) & 1) ^ b) << n; }
```